# Self-explaining version of bash expressions

Tags: bash

Expressions like this are short, but not super-readable:

```
if [ -f .bash_profile ]; then
    ...
fi
```

There are also other possible flags for expressions, for instance:

> Description
>
> -d file
>   True if file is a directory.
>
> -e file
>   True if file exists.
>
> -f file
>   True if file exists and is a regular file.
>
> -L file
>   True if file is a symbolic link.
>
> -z string
>   True if string is empty. (most innatural IMO)
>
> -n string
>   True if string is not empty.
>
> ... and others...

**Are there longer self-explaining versions? Something like:**

```
[ --file-exists .bash_profile ]
```

Comment: You can always just add a comment: `if [ -f .bash_profile ]; then # if file exists`

Comment: Most shell commands are optimized for quick typing, not readability. (Or maybe for using as little disk space as possible in a script; one is a bonus from the other.)

Comment: These aren't "bash expressions". It's not even a bash-specific syntax, or even a shell syntax; it's the POSIX test command, same thing as `/usr/bin/test`, just a version built into the shell for performance reasons. But point is, you could call `/usr/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/test` from a Python program or a C program or any old thing, not just a shell script, and have the exact same behavior; the versions that actually are *different* because they're built into the shell have different calling behavior for compatibility reasons (ie. `[[ ]]`).

Comment: See the relevant POSIX specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely well documented already. [As you can see](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), there is no long-form version of those conditional expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use these in a more readable way, you can always create your own functions:

```
function is_a_file() { test -f "$1"; }
function is_a_dir() { test -d "$1"; }
#etc.

if is_a_file /the/file/name
then
    #do something
fi
```

`test` is the canonical name for the `[` command that is typically used. Its return value becomes the return value of the function, so we can use it in exactly the same way in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, use comments or use something less cryptic like Python